# Node.js cluster module cannot use all the cpu cores when running inside docker container

Tags: node.js, docker

When run Node.js cluster module on my physical machine, the `os.cpus().length` will get **`4`**, but after put the app inside docker container then it returns **`2`**!

I generally know this is because that by default `Golang` will just run on one single core, that's why here the cluster module only can see one single CPU core (2 logical cores).

If I want my cluster module to utilize all the physical CPU cores, what is the proper way to achieve that?

I tried to play with the `--cpuset-cpus=0-1` options, till now haven't figure out much.

I am thinking if I just create an **arbitrary** amount of workers, will that really can utilize all the CPU cores? The `os.cpus().length` here is just used to figure out how many cpu cores the machine has, I can get around of this by calling into shell script. That means this question can be just simply equal to Node.js `os.cpus()` API is not compatible with docker? Is that true?

Comment: Are you on Windows or Mac?

Comment: @Robert Mac, how does that matter?

Comment: Docker on Mac is running on a Linux  virtual machine. Click the whale in task bar and configure the assigned amount of cpu cores.

Comment: @Robert, oh yeah, verified, yes, it is, than u very much.

Comment: @Inshi you're welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your docker machine uses default 2 core. On mac you can change the amount in advanced.
[image]